# I compiled the code in release mode and started debugging the code and I'm getting these errors

Tags: debugging, stm32

the first line is the one reported as an error
08000a5c:   bl      0x8000f2c <HAL_Init>

08000f2c:   ldr     r2, [pc, #60]   ; (0x8000f6c <HAL_Init+64>)

Has anyone ever encountered this error?

Comment: You seem to not understand what Release builds are for (certainly not for debugging). You do a Release build after you've tested and debugged your project to a point where everything is working and you're confident to release it to your customers. Then you do a Release build, flash it to your products and ship them to customers. Before that final step you use Debug build for the actual testing and debugging.

Comment: After developing the code in debug mode. I had a fully functional project, the micro was able to program the cyclone III. When I loaded the release version, the cyclone III cannot be programmed. The data coming from the micro via SPI are correct. Searching the net I found that the problem could be the optimization that introduces the compiler for the release version. I would like to know how to disable these optimizations from CubeIDe if it is possible. Thanks for the answer, now I understand that the release mode should never be tested in debug. However at first I worked on the debug version

Comment: If you simply want to disable optimization in release builds open Project, Properties. Click on C/C++ Build, Settings. On top of the window choose Configuration: Release. Then MCU GCC Compiler, Optimization. Choose Optimization level: None (-O0)

Comment: Thanks for the help at the moment it works correctly, the cyclone III can be programmed, although I still have to do all the tests on the FPGA, just to be sure to verify that everything is working correctly

Answer (score 2):

When you run an STM32 program in debug mode, it automatically puts a breakpoint on the first line of main(). Which is normally a call to HAL_Init().

So this isn't an error, you've just stopped at that breakpoint. Hit the "continue" icon to run your code.

Comment: Instead, it seems like a mistake. This is what CubeIDE provides on the left side of the window: No source available for "main () at 0x8000a5c" and I can't go ahead with debugging. This only happens to me in release mode. If I compile in debug mode I have no problem debugging the code.
Instead if I go on this path up CubeIde: Project => C / C ++ Build => setting and go to the Tool Setting window => MCU GCC Assembler => Debugging and set the debug level to (Maximum-g3) I am always in the mode release I can debug the code even if it gives me that error and it stops there
HAL_Init (); crashes

Comment: @Soufiane Yes indeed, a release build will generally not include debug symbols. You can enable them as you describe, but you'll probably not have a very pleasant debugging experience. The compiler will have transformed your code, eliminated bits, inlined functions, etc.

Note that debugger generally won't tell you about errors. That is not a concept the debugger knows about. It can stop at breakpoints etc, but that's about it. It sounds like this is what is happening for you.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
I'm new to firmware programming and I need to use a U585 series microcntroller to program a cyclone III FPGA. Could you tell me how to eliminate the optimizations introduced by the compiler and if there is the possibility to do it directly from CubeIDe

Comment: @Soufiane You should probably start a new question about programming an FPGA. To eliminate the optimisations, just build a Debug build of your code. If you're worried about the code size, you can change the optimisation for the Debug build from -O0 to -Og and still get a good debugging experience.